# Pagination part missing in email undeliverable options in CF2016 admin

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfadmin

I've working with CF2016. In my local I've tested about send an email. For example I've tested it localhost:8501/testSendMail.cfm.
But I could not able to see the pagination options in coldfusion email undeliverable option. See [image: unDeliverNotShowing.png]

While I'm testing this in my cf11 I can able to receive mail in my coldfusion administrator part & I can see pagination options in email undeliverable option in admin.  Please see my undeliverImage.PNG.

[image]

Not sure Why the options are not showing in my CF2016 admin. Any one can help, what is the mistake in my admin settings ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Odds are the newer CF doesn't show the controls unless you reach more than a page's worth of emails. You might ask cf.install@adobe.com for more info.

Comment: something is wrong with your cf2016, because my cf2016 looks like your cf11 pic

Comment: It must be due to some kind of issue with CF16 setup.

Comment: Thank your for your response on this. I've found the root cause of this problem why it's happen. As we know we are configure our application with Apache / IIS. I'm using Apache. And it's was set alise as "Alias /cf_scripts "C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\cf_scripts". But I could not able to see the cf_script folder in my webroot. So the problem is in my installation process. Once again thank you all for attention on these.